# Can i take in account the request time to get the time difference between JS client and Server?

Tags: javascript, time, client-server

I would like to calculate the difference between the Javascript client and any server requested by the app (that can be local, but also remote), in a quite precise way (order of a second). The goal is to be able to deliver short-time expiration stamps.

I can get both times, as well as inject a server timestamp in the HTML page to get a reference for comparison.

However, is there an easy way to take in account the time it takes for the client to reach the server, and back, so that the time difference can be accurate? Interested to know also if you have reasons not to use this way of doing things..

If the answer is a way to use variables to calculate, you can keep your explanation simple and just state the variables, no use to write all the code.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a little general and depends on what exactly you want to do.

First of all, you need to take into account that the server and the client don't have the same time, a client may not even have the correct date, so all the javascript timestamps should be saved in difference to a relative point.

Using ajax for every request may be easier for you (you can easy collect data about the connection)

**Estimating the server time**

The main problem here is the internet connection or if the server do some heavy work, the server execution time.

You can measure the time to "ping" the server, by making a normal request to the server and mesuring the time the request took to be served.

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
// Make the request
var ping_time = new Date().getTime() - start;
```

The request takes about `ping_time/2` to be servered by the server and `ping_time/2` for the client to get the response.

You can also make the server responce with the time in timestamp on this request (geting the timestamp in ajax is faster because of the small content). In order to be able to find the server time.

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
// Make the request
var serverTime = request_responce;
var ping_time = new Date().getTime() - start;
// Estimate server's time
server_time_now = serverTime + (ping_time / 2);
```

In order to be able to estimate the server time in the future you can also save with the `server_time_now` the `client_time_now = new Date().getTime()`.
And make a function to calculate the difference.

```
function getServerTimeEstimation(){
    return server_time_now + (new Date().getTime() - client_time_now);
}
```

Now you have an estimation of the server time, you can also remake the server time estimation and check if you got about the same estimation (just to check if the estimation was right).

**Estimate ping**

An other issue is that for the short time timestamps you may use a fixed number of ms or use the estimation of the ping. By using a fixed number of ms (ex 5*1000 = 5 secs) you may have problems if a user has a slow connection.

```
// Short time timestamp
stt = getServerTimeEstimation() + (5*1000)
```

If you use ex. 5*ping it may be better but you need to keep tracking the ping

```
// Short time timestamp
stt = getServerTimeEstimation() + (5*ping)
```

So you may need to make a ajax wrapper that measure the ping each time and keeps updating it.

```
// Measure new ping
new_ping = ...;
// Adjust ping a little
ping = ping * 0.7 + new_ping * 0.3;
```

Comment: thanks, i thought about timing differences on both sides, but surprisingly not about sending a ping just for that. I wait a little more before accepting the answer, but it helped. To be more precise, this concerns 2 different projects, one in which i want to make a "real time turned-based" game that adapts turns duration to speed connexion. For the second it is for work and much more complex, and i might not be able to implement because of connexion that are unstable.. i'll maybe update. Thx again!